# Importing an existing project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to add [this ListView project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27600/Developing-an-Autofilter-ListView) into my own. It works fine if I add it and then use "Set as startup project". If I use my current project and try to open it's main window through mine using:

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newWindow = new ScottLogic.Window1();
        newWindow.Show();
    }
```

I get this error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'Initialization of 'ScottLogic.Controls.FilterableListView' threw an exception.' Line number '159' and line position '18'.
```

I already added the project in references, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: What's in "Line number '159' and line position '18'"?

Comment: It's an empty line, right befor the start of this:         private bool IsPropertyFiltered(String property)
        {
            foreach (String filterProperty in currentFilters.Keys)
            {
                FilterStruct filter = (FilterStruct)currentFilters[filterProperty];
                if (filter.property == property)
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

Comment: If, in your source code, it shows as an empty line check your referencing the project and not a dll.  You could be referencing an out of date dll

Comment: Ups, think I might have been looking in the wrong place. line 159 in main XAML <slogic:FilterableListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">. Hovering over it sais "Cannot locate resource 'controls/filterlistviewdictionary.xaml"